# How to add element attribute value as a selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get clicked element attribute value to a variable and the need to work as a jquery id selector. need to add boxid value to in side "" with # for show that specific id based element

```
$("[data-toggle=modalBx]").click(function(){

        var boxid = $(this).attr('data-target');
        alert(boxid);
        $("boxid value with hash here").show();             

    });
```

Comment: Add your html code.

Comment: You can also try `$(selector).data('target')`

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 (if you don't have hash in boxid):

```
$("[data-toggle=modalBx]").click(function(){

    var boxid = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $("#" + boxid).show();             

});
```

Option 2:

```
$("[data-toggle=modalBx]").click(function(){

    var boxid = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(boxid).show();             

});
```